# Add loss in SRGAN

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to add loss to SRGAN
https://github.com/leftthomas/SRGAN
in train.py

```
g_loss = generator_criterion(fake_out, fake_img, real_img)
```

Can I write a function myself like:

```
def ContentLoss(a, b):
     result = 0
 
     for x, y in zip(a, b):
         shape = x.shape
         k = np.prod(shape[0:])
         diff = x - y
         #l2 norm
         diff = np. sqrt(np. sum(np. square(diff)))
         diff = diff*diff
         diff = diff / k
         result = result + diff
        
 
     return result
```

And add it to the original loss as follows:

```
a = ContentLoss(a,b)
g_loss = generator_criterion(fake_out, fake_img, real_img) + a
```

Is there a way to calculate the gradient of this loss during training?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: "Will this work?" Well, you can just type that in your IDE and run it. Why do you think it will or will not work? Please [edit] the post to contain the actual question you have.

Comment: I see that most people inherit nn.Module or define forward and backward functions when customizing loss, but they are not in my loss. I don’t know if there is a way to calculate the gradient in backward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project you linked uses PyTorch. Assuming that you are also using it, you can just implement your loss using PyTorch instead of numpy and your're covered.

```py
import torch
import math


def ContentLoss(a, b):
     result = 0
     for x, y in zip(a, b):
         shape = x.shape
         k = math.prod(shape[0:])  # you can also use np, but not torch
         diff = x - y
         #l2 norm
         # just replacing np with torch
         diff = torch.sqrt(torch.sum(torch.square(diff)))
         diff = diff*diff  # torch differentiates through these as well
         diff = diff / k
         result = result + diff
     return result

# I assume you only want gradients for a (are these your model outputs?)
# This is just test data anyway. If this is your model output, 
# it will pass on the gradients to the weights.
a = [
    torch.tensor([1.0, 1.0, 1.0], requires_grad=True),
    torch.tensor([0.0, -1.0, 1.0], requires_grad=True),
    torch.tensor([7.0, 6.0, -5.0], requires_grad=True),
]
b = [
    torch.tensor([1.0, 0.0, 1.0]),
    torch.tensor([1.0, -2.0, 3.0]),
    torch.tensor([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
]

loss = ContentLoss(a, b)
loss.backward()  # computes the gradients
for x in a:
    print(f"a={a}, gradient={a.grad}")
```

If you need to keep numpy, you have to create a `torch.autograd.Function` and implement forward and backward: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/examples_autograd/two_layer_net_custom_function.html.

Comment: My A and B are feature maps, so I need to convert the feature map into a tensor and set requires_grad=True, and then change all calculations to torch, right?

Comment: If you want gradients of the feature maps, then yes. If you want to propagate the gradients to parameters, then no. In the second case, the code/model that generates the feature maps also has to be using PyTorch, directly producing tensors.

Comment: In the loss of SRGAN, if I only calculate the gradient of the feature map
g_loss = generator_criterion(fake_out, fake_img, real_img) + a
,Will it help the model training?In second case, if I use the keras model, is there a way to calculate the gradient to parameters?

Comment: If you do what you outlined in your first comment, then it won't help training (as far as I can see), as `a` will not affect the gradients of the parameters. If you are using a keras model (tensorflow?) there is probably a way to do the same as the above in tensorflow, but I can't help you there. Otherwise, convert to PyTorch.